# Layout toolbar disabled/greyed out in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, layouts

For some reason, when I removed and replaced toolbars  in an .mxd document the Layout toolbar is greyed out.

I've tried opening/closing the document and ArcMap, in addition to re-adding the toolbar several times, and also tried going into Data Frame Properties and ensured that automatic radio button was checked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure you refresh after changing to layout view if legend and other bars are still inactive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you're using the Layout View.

Of the 3 little buttons under the map data window, the left is data (map) view, the middle is layout view - this is when the layout toolbar is active, the right is refresh.